# Sun's OpenDS LDAP Server - Is it Supported?

Tags: ldap, opends, opendj

We have investigated Sun's Open DS LDAP server, and it fits all of our fairly simple requirements.

Basically, we just wish to use it's out of the box password policy, and harness the replication facility, to replicate between 2 data centres.

However, it's last released version was around 2010 time? This is from what I can see, please correct me if this is wrong?

So, the question is, would we be unwise to choose Sun's Open DS as our LDAP server that we put our authentication functionality on? AS mentioned, we have only a small set of requirements, and if these are tested by us and are proved to work on the Open DS server, do we need to worry too much about the future?

What are the fallbacks, in case a future bug is encountered?

My boss is reluctant to pay any money for a licence, hence the Open DJ and Oracle Unified Directory solutions are ruled out.

Therefore, the only alternative is to either write our own Authentication module, (using our RDBMS DB and schema that we will add to),or to use Sun Open DS.

What are the pitfalls of using Open DS , as it may be unsupported? Does anyone know? Thanks

Comment: There are other alternatives. OpenLDAP 2.4.34 supports all that, and I'd be surprised if ApacheDS didn't support it as well: I know that it supports password policies, don't know about replication.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, the OpenDS project is no longer supported or updated. OpenDJ is actively developed as an open source project and freely available from the project website. You do not need to purchase a license to use it.
ForgeRock is offering support subscriptions for OpenDJ.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **OpenDS is not developed anymore** by Oracle engineers. It is only developed by the OpenDS community, but it seems like a stopped project to me. The former (French) OpenDS developers (who created Sun Directory Server Enterprise Edition 7, now called Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition 11.1.1.7.0) work on Oracle Unified Directory 11gR2 right now.

Background: As Oracle bought Sun, OpenDS transformed into Oracle Unified Directory. Oracle wants its customers to pay for any further development and enhancement its developers make.

Comment: May I correct that ? Part of the (french) OpenDS developers remain at Oracle. A few of us moved to ForgeRock and we are continuing building 100% open source ldap directories as the OpenDJ project.